# RavenDB - Replication, WaitAsync and different E-TAG

Tags: c#, ravendb, document-database

I am trying to implement proper Load Balancing of `RavenDB`. I am using 2 `ravendb`servers. I am using `RavenDB` version `3.0`.

Here is my code (it looks as it looks because I need to have that operation synchronous):

```
                session.Store(document);
                session.SaveChanges();

                var result = Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    var store = RavenDocumentStore as DocumentStore;
                    if (session != null)
                    {
                        Etag documentsEtag = session.Advanced.GetEtagFor(document);
                        var waitAsync = store?.Replication.WaitAsync(documentsEtag);
                        if (waitAsync != null) await waitAsync;
                    }
                    return true;
                }).Result;
```

Unfortunately I am getting an error:

> One or more errors occurred. -> Could only confirm that the specified
>   Etag 01000000-0000-0095-0000-000000115E65 was replicated to 0 of 1
>   servers after 00:01:00.0087214 Details: Url: my-second-box-url, Etag:
>   FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF

When I go to raven boxes, I can see that the document has been replicated, it has different E-TAG though. I think that might be the reason it cannot find it.

I did a simple test as well. I used `RavenDB Studio` interface and updated document on one of the boxes, it has been replicated quick, but E-TAGs were different. I am somehow missing the idea of E-TAGs and replication I guess.

Is there any setting to keep source E-Tag in replication process?

---

EDIT:

Added fiddler output:

```
curl -k -i --raw -o 0.dat "http://SOURCE_IP_ADDRESS:8080/databases/DATABASE_NAME/replication/topology" -H "Raven-Client-Version: 3.0.0.0" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" -H "Host: SOURCE_IP_ADDRESS:8080" -H "Connection: Keep-Alive"
curl -k -i --raw -o 1.dat "http://SOURCE_IP_ADDRESS:8080/docs?id=Raven%%2FDatabases%%2FDATABASE_NAME" -H "Raven-Client-Version: 3.0.0.0" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" -H "Host: SOURCE_IP_ADDRESS:8080" -H "Connection: Keep-Alive"
curl -k -i --raw -o 2.dat -X POST "http://SOURCE_IP_ADDRESS:8080/databases/DATABASE_NAME/bulk_docs" -H "Raven-Client-Version: 3.0.0.0" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" -H "Content-Encoding: gzip" -H "Host: SOURCE_IP_ADDRESS:8080" -H "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" -H "Expect: 100-continue"
curl -k -i --raw -o 3.dat "http://SOURCE_IP_ADDRESS:8080/databases/DATABASE_NAME/replication/topology" -H "Raven-Client-Version: 3.0.0.0" -H "If-None-Match: \"01000000-0000-0001-0000-00000000A243\"" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" -H "Host: SOURCE_IP_ADDRESS:8080"
curl -k -i --raw -o 4.dat "http://SOURCE_IP_ADDRESS:8080/databases/DATABASE_NAME/stats" -H "Raven-Client-Version: 3.0.0.0" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" -H "Host: SOURCE_IP_ADDRESS:8080"
curl -k -i --raw -o 5.dat "http://TARGET_IP_ADDRESS:8080/databases/DATABASE_NAME/replication/lastEtag?from=http%%3A%%2F%%2FSOURCE_IP_ADDRESS%%3A8080%%2Fdatabases%%2FDATABASE_NAME&dbid=f570866b-4b62-48d5-aef1-97b2217cef16" -H "Raven-Client-Version: 3.0.0.0" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" -H "Host: TARGET_IP_ADDRESS:8080"
curl -k -i --raw -o 6.dat "http://TARGET_IP_ADDRESS:8080/databases/DATABASE_NAME/replication/lastEtag?from=http%%3A%%2F%%2FSOURCE_IP_ADDRESS%%3A8080%%2Fdatabases%%2FDATABASE_NAME&dbid=f570866b-4b62-48d5-aef1-97b2217cef16" -H "Raven-Client-Version: 3.0.0.0" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" -H "Host: TARGET_IP_ADDRESS:8080"
curl -k -i --raw -o 7.dat "http://TARGET_IP_ADDRESS:8080/databases/DATABASE_NAME/replication/lastEtag?from=http%%3A%%2F%%2FSOURCE_IP_ADDRESS%%3A8080%%2Fdatabases%%2FDATABASE_NAME&dbid=f570866b-4b62-48d5-aef1-97b2217cef16" -H "Raven-Client-Version: 3.0.0.0" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" -H "Host: TARGET_IP_ADDRESS:8080"
curl -k -i --raw -o 8.dat "http://TARGET_IP_ADDRESS:8080/databases/DATABASE_NAME/replication/lastEtag?from=http%%3A%%2F%%2FSOURCE_IP_ADDRESS%%3A8080%%2Fdatabases%%2FDATABASE_NAME&dbid=f570866b-4b62-48d5-aef1-97b2217cef16" -H "Raven-Client-Version: 3.0.0.0" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" -H "Host: TARGET_IP_ADDRESS:8080"
curl -k -i --raw -o 9.dat "http://TARGET_IP_ADDRESS:8080/databases/DATABASE_NAME/replication/lastEtag?from=http%%3A%%2F%%2FSOURCE_IP_ADDRESS%%3A8080%%2Fdatabases%%2FDATABASE_NAME&dbid=f570866b-4b62-48d5-aef1-97b2217cef16" -H "Raven-Client-Version: 3.0.0.0" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" -H "Host: TARGET_IP_ADDRESS:8080"
curl -k -i --raw -o 10.dat "http://TARGET_IP_ADDRESS:8080/databases/DATABASE_NAME/replication/lastEtag?from=http%%3A%%2F%%2FSOURCE_IP_ADDRESS%%3A8080%%2Fdatabases%%2FDATABASE_NAME&dbid=f570866b-4b62-48d5-aef1-97b2217cef16" -H "Raven-Client-Version: 3.0.0.0" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" -H "Host: TARGET_IP_ADDRESS:8080"
curl -k -i --raw -o 11.dat "http://TARGET_IP_ADDRESS:8080/databases/DATABASE_NAME/replication/lastEtag?from=http%%3A%%2F%%2FSOURCE_IP_ADDRESS%%3A8080%%2Fdatabases%%2FDATABASE_NAME&dbid=f570866b-4b62-48d5-aef1-97b2217cef16" -H "Raven-Client-Version: 3.0.0.0" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" -H "Host: TARGET_IP_ADDRESS:8080"
curl -k -i --raw -o 12.dat "http://TARGET_IP_ADDRESS:8080/databases/DATABASE_NAME/replication/lastEtag?from=http%%3A%%2F%%2FSOURCE_IP_ADDRESS%%3A8080%%2Fdatabases%%2FDATABASE_NAME&dbid=f570866b-4b62-48d5-aef1-97b2217cef16" -H "Raven-Client-Version: 3.0.0.0" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" -H "Host: TARGET_IP_ADDRESS:8080"
curl -k -i --raw -o 13.dat "http://TARGET_IP_ADDRESS:8080/databases/DATABASE_NAME/replication/lastEtag?from=http%%3A%%2F%%2FSOURCE_IP_ADDRESS%%3A8080%%2Fdatabases%%2FDATABASE_NAME&dbid=f570866b-4b62-48d5-aef1-97b2217cef16" -H "Raven-Client-Version: 3.0.0.0" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" -H "Host: TARGET_IP_ADDRESS:8080"
curl -k -i --raw -o 14.dat "http://TARGET_IP_ADDRESS:8080/databases/DATABASE_NAME/replication/lastEtag?from=http%%3A%%2F%%2FSOURCE_IP_ADDRESS%%3A8080%%2Fdatabases%%2FDATABASE_NAME&dbid=f570866b-4b62-48d5-aef1-97b2217cef16" -H "Raven-Client-Version: 3.0.0.0" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" -H "Host: TARGET_IP_ADDRESS:8080"
curl -k -i --raw -o 15.dat "http://TARGET_IP_ADDRESS:8080/databases/DATABASE_NAME/replication/lastEtag?from=http%%3A%%2F%%2FSOURCE_IP_ADDRESS%%3A8080%%2Fdatabases%%2FDATABASE_NAME&dbid=f570866b-4b62-48d5-aef1-97b2217cef16" -H "Raven-Client-Version: 3.0.0.0" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" -H "Host: TARGET_IP_ADDRESS:8080"
```

Last request is repeated until it crashes, with exception given above.

Looks like etag request's response is:

```
{"MaxNumberOfItemsToReceiveInSingleBatch":null,"LastDocumentEtag":"FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF","LastAttachmentEtag":"FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF","ServerInstanceId":"26174fc9-74f5-410a-bef0-0f7cd844c481","Source":"http://SOURCE-RAVEN-SERVER:8080/databases/DATABASE-NAME","LastModified":"2017-02-06T09:05:32.8443655Z","LastBatchSize":1}
```

Comment: What is the valid of `documentsEtag` ? What happens if you move the line immediately after the SaveChanges? Are you disposing the session?
Note that the `FFFF...` etag means invalid etag.

Comment: when I debug through, it has first value from exception:  01000000-0000-0095-0000-000000115E65. I will give it a try and move it immiadiately after the SaveChanges and let you know, as soon as check it. Yes I am disposing session, code I pasted is inside using statement.

Comment: I checked your suggestion, and moved etag line just after SaveChanges, behavior is exactly the same. Exception: Could only confirm that the specified Etag 01000000-0000-0097-0000-0000000000EA was replicated to 0 of 1 servers after 00:01:00.0123030
Details: Url: my-url, Etag: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF.  Etag from first part of exception is the same as in documentsEtag localvariable.

Comment: Something is strange here, it should use the doc etag. Can you send the fiddler output to the mailing list?

Comment: Do you mean Fiddler from both RavenDb boxes or client that perform saving operation?

Comment: From the client

Comment: @AyendeRahien I added export from fiddler as curl script. Does it help?

Comment: the curl doesn't help, please send a SAZ file to the mailing list. SO is not really meant for back and forth like this.